# heidisql. После экспорта часть таблиц в БД превратились в представления

Tags: mysql, база-данных

**Используется**
MySQL 5,7 - x64
Open Server - последний
heidisql

Выполнил экспорт .
Перезагрузил сервер.
Захожу в БД,а там вместо некоторых таблиц появились представления с наименованиями таблиц.

1. Из БД1 (находится в **ПАПКА 1**) экспортирую БД1
2. В БД2 (находится в **ПАПКА 2**) импортирую  из файла *.sql из п.1

Прилагаю скрин.
Слева показано БД1 после экспорта.
Справа показано БД2 после импорта.

**Вопрос.**
В чём причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавлении в **БД1** нового представления для таблицы **"trg_01_test_log"**,
всё работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В недоумении. Экспорт никак не влияет на БД. Это не импорт, он только читает.

Comment: @Akina Дополнил вопрос. Приложил скрин. Цитирую: "Слева показано БД1 после экспорта.
Справа показано БД2 после импорта."

Comment: @Mike Дополнил вопрос. Приложил скрин. Цитирую: "Слева показано БД1 после экспорта. Справа показано БД2 после импорта."

Comment: А попробуйте создать нормальную view в любой БД. heidisql около нее так же напишет "tablespace is missing" ? Если это будет не так, то надо как то узнать где же тот тейблспейс где были выгружаемые таблицы.

Comment: @Mike создал. см. вопрос

Comment: Ну значит пока вы делали экспорт что то   случилось с файлом innodb в котором данные таблиц хранились. остается узнать не хранились ли данные таблиц в файле в который вы решили экспорт сделать